# How to add text boxes in MVC when binding a view to an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am working on this project. We are using EF and backside data models. We are mapping them to viewmodels that have the same property names. This has created 4 separate view models, which I'm ok with. Now, I have organizations that can have 2 addresses, multiple access codes and multiple domain addresses. In my partial views, I have to bind the view to an IEnumerable to list all of the possible codes/domains/etc. When I'm in the "details" page for an organization, which is using a details page that is populated by partials, I would like to add a text box for adding a new access code, or domain. Unfortunatly, I can't figure out how to achive this. 
Here is my code:

**ViewModel for OrganizationAccessCodes**:

```
namespace AdminTool.Models.ViewModel
{
public class OrganizationAccessCodeView
{
    [AtLeastOneRequired(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AdminResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "OrganizationAccessCodeRequired")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(AdminResource), Name = "OrganizationAccessCode")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(0-9)", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AdminResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "OrganizationAccessCodeFormatError")]
    public string AccessCode { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is the Details html:

```
@model AdminTool.Models.ViewModel.OrganizationView
@using AdminTool.App_GlobalResources;



@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}


<div id="idm_main">
<div class="form_section">
    <h3>@AdminResource.OrganizationDetailsHeader</h3>

    <div class="form_item">
        <h4>@AdminResource.OrganizationNameHeader</h4>
        <div class="item">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrganizationName)
        </div>
        @Html.Partial("_AddressPartial", Model.OrganizationAddress)
    </div><br /><br />
    <div class="form_item">
        <h4>@AdminResource.OrganizationAccessCodeHeader</h4>
        @Html.Partial("_AccessCodePartial", Model.AccessCodes)
    </div><br /><br />
    <div class="form_item">
        <h4>@AdminResource.OrganizationDomainsHeader</h4>
        @Html.Partial("_EmailDomainPartial", Model.DomainAddresses)
    </div>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is the partial for the access code:

```
@model IEnumerable<AdminTool.Models.ViewModel.OrganizationAccessCodeView>  

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @item.AccessCode
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Deactivate", "Edit", new {})
    </td>
</tr>
}

<div class="form_item">
<div class="item">
    @Html.LabelFor()
</div>
<div class="item">
    @Html.TextBoxFor()
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor()
</div>
</div>
```

I'm not completely done with the partial view because of this problem I'm having. I want to know if there is a way (other than Tuple) in order to have a text box for the access code object that is in the view model?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what your label and textbox are for in your partial view. If the property is called Address:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => item.Address)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.Address)
}
```

Comment: The code you have there won't work, because of the view being bound to: IEnumerable<AdminTool.Models.ViewModel.OrganizationAccessCodeView>
I don't want a textbox for each access code that is in the enum, i only want 1 textbox that i will have a button next to that will add another access code to the list. that's why i have the data annotation in the viewmodel.